# How to stop moving map when marker is moving in leaflet animatedMarker

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet in my project. For moving the markers on the map i am using this plugin.But i am getting a serious problem with it.On my map several vehicles are there on different positions(GPS locations).I am getting new positions(data) via web socket.So while one vehicle is moving and suddenly another vehicle started to move the map,immediately moves to that position.I want wherever the marker may move but the map should always be stand and still. Can this be done in anyway? I am really in trouble for this and in need of help.

Here is my code snippet-

```
 vehicleAnimatedMarker = L.animatedMarker(lines.getLatLngs(), {
                        icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                            icon: 'truck',
                            markerColor: 'green',
                            prefix: 'fa',
                            spin: false
                        }),
                        autoStart: false,
                        clickable: true,
                        title: searchTitle,
                        totalData: details.position
                    });
                    vehicleAnimatedMarker.on('click', function () {
                        showVehicleSummary(details.id);
                    })
                    vehicleAnimatedMarker.addTo(map).bindPopup("truck " + getVehicleNameByVehicleId(details.id) + " is moving.").openPopup();
                    var markerItem = {id: details.id, marker: vehicleAnimatedMarker};
                    vehiclesAnimatedMarkersArray.push(markerItem);
                    vehicleAnimatedMarker.setDistance(3);
                    vehicleAnimatedMarker.setInterval(36);
                    vehicleAnimatedMarker.start();
```

Thanks in advance. Any kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `{autoPan: false}` to your `marker`.

```
marker.bindPopup("yourHTMLForPopup", {autoPan:false}).openPopup();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that because you are using
`vehicleAnimatedMarker.addTo(map).bindPopup("truck " + getVehicleNameByVehicleId(details.id) + " is moving.").openPopup();`
Leaflet is moving the map every time `openPopup()` is called, because that is the default behavior.Fortunately Leaflet has a option for Popups called `autoPan`(http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-autopan), which you can set to `false` to disable this behavior.Your `bindPopup` call should look like `bindPopup("truck " + getVehicleNameByVehicleId(details.id) + " is moving.",{autoPan:false})`